# Pywin32 Saving as XLSM file instead of XLSX

Tags: python, pywin32

When I currently attempt to save an XLSM file like so:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

# Open Excel workbook
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(r"C:\Users\ryan\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")

# Make some changes
# blah blah blah

# Save the workbook in XLSM format with new name

wb.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\ryan\Desktop\Book1 - XLSM.xlsm")
xl.Quit()
```

I am given the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject Add>", line 7, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel'
, 'This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file e
xtension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing t
he Save as type.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

How do I save as a new file format?

Note- this causes the same error when trying to save a file that was already an XLSM, as an XLSM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the file is determined by the [`FileFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) parameter that you specify when you call `SaveAs`. Since you don't specify a value, the default value of .xlsx is chosen. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) lists the possible values. You need to use `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`.

The code would be:

```
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
....
wb.SaveAs(filename, FileFormat=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to this. Yes I'd figured this out shortly after posting the question, but I just used the number 52 as the file format instead of typing the whole "xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled".

Comment: You can also use the enums from win32com like: ``win32com.client.constants.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled``