# pywin/win32com file access error when saving a macro-enabled spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32, win32com

I have the following code that reads an existing Excel file, adds a macro, and then tries to save it to a different macro-enabled excel file.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import comtypes, comtypes.client

name="//path//to//test1.xlsx"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
xl=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible=True
ss = xl.Workbooks.Open(name, False, True)
ss.Worksheets(sheetName).Activate()
xlmodule = ss.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  
VBAcode='''sub VBAMacro()
       Range("A1").Value = 1
      end sub'''

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(VBAcode)

#xl.Run(name+'!VBAMacro')

ss.SaveAs(Filename=name[:-5] + '-macro.xlsm', FileFormat=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)

xl.Quit()
```

In doing this, I have been taking into consideration the questions about `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306275/pywin32-saving-as-xlsm-file-instead-of-xlsx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975165/saving-as-macro-enabled-workbook). However, when I try to run this I get the error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file ...
```

I have tested this code without the SaveAs line and it reads the file ok, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `0x80020009 DISP_E_EXCEPTION Exception occurred.` so it's an IDispatch error.

Comment: What is an IDispatch error? Is this a clue to a solution?

Comment: The method you are using to access Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the origin of the problem was the way the file path is processed. After several trials and errors, it seems the right way to write paths (at least in Windows OS) is using double backslashes: `"C:\\Users\\blablah\\"`.